# How to know when a widget is being rendered?

Tags: java, gwt

Is there a way to handle or at least know when the Widget is being rendered on the browser screen? I mean when the render event is about to happen for a widget or when render is done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every widget has protected `onLoad()` method and this method called immediately after a widget becomes attached to the browser's document.

[image: The following diagram shows (or at least attempts to show) rendering process]
See [GWT Rendering Process](http://davidmaddison.blogspot.com/2008/12/gwt-rendering-process.html) explanation on David Maddison's blog.